# Can I count a certain Scenario in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table looks like this

```
ID | I  | II | III | IV | V  |
===============================
1  | 1  | 0  | NULL|NULL|NULL|
2  |NULL|NULL|NULL | 0  |  1 |
3  | 1  |  0 |  0  |NULL|NULL|
4  |NULL|NULL|NULL |NULL| 1  |
.    .     .    .    .    .
.    .     .    .    .    .  
.    .     .    .    .    .
```

I am using SQL Server 2014.

I am looking to count the number of ID that has the scenario like #1 and #3. Is there a query that can do that? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "a scenario like #1 and #3"? The exact same values in all columns?

Comment: What I mean is that I want to calculate the number of people who has values in certain stage but end with NULL. Like #1, it has values in stage I and II, but then 'NULL' in the following stages. If a particular ID starts with 'NULL' but ended with a value, I don't care about that. With the query you provide, do I need to specify every possibilities in the query? In my table, there might exists some data like the followings, ID | I | II | III | IV | V | 5 | NULL| NULL | 0 | 1 | NULL | 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | NULL | . . . I would care #5, not #6

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that when you write *scenario like #1 and #3* you really mean you want to count rows that have values equal to what row 1 **or** row 3 has. If that's the case, you would do something like this.

```
select count(*)
from YourTable
where (I = 1
        and II = 0
        and III is null
        and IV is null
        and V is null)
    or (I = 1
        and II = 0
        and III = 0
        and IV is null
        and V is null);
```

Alternatively, you could simplify the above query a bit to the following form:

```
select count(*)
from YourTable
where (I = 1
        and II = 0
        and (III = 0 or III is null)
        and IV is null
        and V is null);
```

Perhaps something like this is what you're looking for:

```
select *
from YourTable
where coalesce(I, II, III, IV, V) is not null;
```

Or this:

```
select
    ValidCnt = sum(case
        when coalesce(I, II, III, IV, V) is not null then 1
        else 0
        end),
    InvalidCnt = sum(case
        when coalesce(I, II, III, IV, V) is null then 1
        else 0
        end)
from YourTable;
```

Comment: What I mean is that I want to calculate the number of people who has values in certain stage but end with NULL. Like #1, it has values in stage I and II, but then 'NULL' in the following stages. If a particular ID starts with 'NULL' but ended with a value, I don't care about that. 

With the query you provide, do I need to specify every possibilities in the query?
In my table, there might exists some data like the followings,
ID |  I       |  II       | III | IV |     V    |
 5 | NULL| NULL | 0  | 1   | NULL |
 6 |  1      |   0      |  0  | 1  |  NULL |
.
.
.
I would care #5, not #6

Comment: If you only care that something starts with a non-null value. In other words, something must have a non-null value in I for you to care, then I think I you'd have to do is something like this `select count(*)
from YourTable
where I is not null;`.

Comment: I only care about something that "ends" with NULL, but NULL does not have to be at specific column.

Comment: Does the column I need to be non-null?

Comment: No, any column doesn't have to be non-null. Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: See the latest addition, if you're looking for rows where there is at least one column has a non-null value, then use `coalesce`.

Comment: If there is no such condition, is there still a way to count the number?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM YourTabel WHERE ISNULL(I,-1)!=-1

Desc: I is your column name & you can specify more columns in where condition.

Comment: Can you explain the ISNULL(I,-1)!=-1 part to me? Thank you.

Comment: This is logically the same as `select count(*) from YourTable where I is not null;`, but is not advised.

Comment: when you compare null in your where condition it convert every thing to null, so i use ISNULL(I,-1) mean return -1 when Column I =-1 and then compare ISNULL(I,-1) with -1 if it found Null it will return -1 so condition will be true and it will be not count

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
CREATE TABLE Joe ( ID INT , I int NULL, II int NULL, III int NULL, IV int NULL, V int NULL)

INSERT INTO Joe VALUES (1, 1, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO Joe VALUES (2, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1)
INSERT INTO Joe VALUES (3, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO Joe VALUES (4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1)

-- SELECT * FROM Joe

SELECT J.* FROM Joe J
JOIN
  ( SELECT J.ID,Count(0) Counter FROM Joe J WHERE J.I IS NOT NULL
     AND J.V IS NULL
   GROUP BY J.Id) JoeCounts ON J.Id = JoeCounts.Id
```